# Не запускается проект в Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Сбилдил, но при запуске вываливается ошибка
`Recreating debt_postgresdb_1 ... error

```
ERROR: for debt_postgresdb_1  cannot stop 
container:
```

2b7fd77cd6a4061caf3ce002e7272aad95dde370af829195d267ebb37feddf6a: Cannot kill container 2b7fd77cd6a4061caf3ce002e7272aad95dde370af829195d267ebb37feddf6a: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
`
Не понимаю при чем тут остановка, если я запускаю проект.

Вот мои настройки:
Dockerfile:

```
`FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY entrypoint.sh .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]`
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
`version: "3"

services:
  postgresdb:
    build:
      context: ./docker/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/init.sql:/docker- 
  entryppoint-initdb.d/init.sql
ports:
  - "5432:5432"

  web:
build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
volumes:
  - ./:/usr/src/app
depends_on:
  - postgresdb`
```

entrypoint.sh :

```
`#! /bin/bash

python manage.py makemigrations --no-input

python manage.py migrate --no-input

exec qunicorn debt.wsgi:application -b 
0.0.0.0:8000 --reload
```

`

requirements.txt:

```
`asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.5
django-simple-menu==1.2.1
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
psycopg2
gunicorn`
```

postgres/Dockerfile

```
`FROM postgres

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
```

postgres/init.sql

```
`CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin';

CREATE DATABASE debt_db;
GANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE debt_db TO 
admin;`
```

Comment: `apparmor_status` - проверка статуса. По этой ошибке чаще всего винят apparmor, некий модуль безопасности, попробуйте если он активный выключить его и проверить `service apparmor stop`

Comment: нет, проблема в путях и разрешении была